Lowest order Raviart Thomas elements
I have questions regarding the implementation of Lowest order Raviart Thomas elements on quadrilaterals, some papers use the basis functions in this form:
for example the right edge: $N = \left[\dfrac{1}{2} (1 + x_i),\, 0\right]$, while in other paper: $N = \left[\dfrac{1}{4} (1 + x_i),\, 0\right]$.
What is the difference between both expressions?
Also some papers multiply by the normal to the edge sign with respect to the global direction after applying Piola transformation while other papers don't.

Have you checked what the reference element is for the two cases? Some people use $[0,1]^2$ as the reference element, others use $[-1,1]^2$ as the unit square.
